# I would like to eliminate frameworks... when I submit a form, how do I catch it with a server-side program?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, server-side

So the answer to this question may be very large and maybe I just need to be pointed in the right direction (probably toward a tutorial or guide of some sort) but I am not sure what to google or what topic to look for. That said...

I began writing web apps recently with Google app engine.  I am trying to learn JS and css and all that good stuff.  I now would like know/learn how to handle submitting a form without any frameworks.  So I fill out the form and hit submit.  This posts info and in usually in GAE I simply map the function that I would like to catch the request to an "action" (in web.xml) and things are taken care of in the background.

I fear I am not articulating my request properly (sorry about that) so here is an example:  I have a form with just a username field.  I hit submit. My method is post and my action is "/doSomething".  I would like (for example) a python class to catch the request and redirect the browser according to the name entered and I would like to use no frameworks if possible (AJAX, node.js... not even sure what is available but this is more an academic exercise so it doesn't matter).

Again, sorry if the request/question is unclear.  I am new to this and am having trouble explaining my problem.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without asking, what is your goal in eliminating frameworks? Or to rephrase, since "framework" is a very broad, nebulous term, what is it, specifically, that you wish to avoid?

Comment: Avoiding frameworks is really impractical.  A better question, since this is just academic anyhow, would be how to accomplish your goal in a given framework.

Comment: Also, AJAX is not a framework.  It's an acronym for Asyncrounous Javascript And XML.  A language and a data stoage facility.

Comment: node.js is not a framework, any more than Python is.

Comment: do you need to do a file upload using the low level basic functions of a specific server side language?

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial on how to program Python web services on GAE without using anything except the libraries that come with Python / are needed to run *anything* on the GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript directly:
Here a sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> TEST PAGE!</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function doSomething(){
            var name = document.getElementById("NAME");
            if (name!=null){
                switch (name.value){
                    case "MIKE":
                        document.location.href = 'http://www.mikePage.html';
                    break;

                    case "PETER":
                        document.location.href = 'http://www.peterPage.html';
                    break;

                    default:
                        document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';                       
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST"  > 
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="TEXT" id="NAME"/>
        <input type="BUTTON" onclick="doSomething()" value="SEND" /> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to make this from the server side, you should use a language like PHP, ASP, Python CGI's, etc.

PHP is a good option.

Regards

Comment: cgi programming... that is the topic I was looking for!  Stack overflow continues to amaze me. Out of my pitiful explanation of the problem and I get the answer on the first response.  You rock. Thanks.